# int to binary python

Tags: python, networking, binary, int

This question is probably very easy for most of you, but i cant find the answer so far.

I'm building a network packet generator that goes like this:

```
class PacketHeader(Packet):
fields = OrderedDict([
    ("head", "\x00"),
    ("headpad", "\x00"),
    ("headlen", "\x1a\x00" ),
    ("presentflag", "\x2e"),
    ("timestamp", "\x43\x10\x58\x16\xa1\x01\x00\x00"),
    ("flag", "\x03"),
    ("Sequencenum", "\x04\x00"),

])
```

Later, I call my class and send the packet like this:

```
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=257))
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=258))
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=259))
```

Unfortunatly, on the wire i have `\x32\x35\x37` (257 in `hex`) instead of having this :`\x01\x01`.

What i would like to do, is being able to:

```
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=257+1))
```

and have it converted to int correctly on the wire

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm confused by perhaps too much information :-) Are you trying to convert an integer to hex? Can you give a simple input and desired output example?

Comment: @martineau: My mistake, you should have read : "\x01\x01". Will modify my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert `int` or any other primitive data type to binary then the `struct` module might help you.

http://docs.python.org/library/struct

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>i', 257)
'\x00\x00\x01\x01'
>>> struct.pack('<i', 257)
'\x01\x01\x00\x00'
>>> struct.unpack('<i', '\x01\x01\x00\x00')
(257,)
>>> struct.unpack('>i', '\x00\x00\x01\x01')
(257,)
```

`ms4py` mentioned you might want to convert 2 byte ints so:

```
>>> struct.pack('>h', 257)
'\x01\x01'
>>> struct.unpack('>h', '\x01\x01')
(257,)
>>>
```

oh and:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>h', '\x10\x00')
(4096,)
>>>
```

Comment: Probably he wants a short (two bytes for an int): `>>> struct.pack('!h', 258)`  
`'\x01\x02'`

Comment: maybe your right, I have no idea :( ... either way the link to the struct should help him decide how he wants to do the conversion, I'll add the example anyway, thank you.

Comment: I should have thought about this !! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an integer and want hex:

```
hex(257)
'0x101'
```

Other way around

```
int('0x101', 16)
257
```

Comment: That's what I thought too .. but seems almost too straight forward :) Maybe OP will clarify

Comment: @Levon Agreed - but figured I'd take a punt ;)

Comment: Who knows, this may just be the ticket .. you'll get my upvote too if OP likes it.

Comment: @Levon I do like the struct answer though - more portable

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me, that you want an integer to binary converter.

If that's the case, then  this should work:

```
def convert(N):
    if not N:
        return ''
    else:
        return "%s%s" %(convert(N/2), N%2)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `bin(N)[2:]` will already do that :)  .. " batteries included" and all that. (didn't downvote!)

Comment: did NOT know about `bin(n)`. Oh God! the number of times I've done this! I've wasted so many LOC in so many modules over the years *sheds a silent tear*

Comment: @Levon the code is the same as '{:b}'.format(257) I think (if you don't want the leading 0x stuff...)

Comment: Downvoter: Would you like to give me a reason so I can upgrade my answer?