# Spliting a 16 bits value to 12+4 python struct

Tags: python, struct, bit

This question is related to this post :
[int to binary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421735/int-to-binary-python)

I have this sequence number I need to increment, now it's fixed and working fine.
But, I just found out that actually the sequence number is not simply a short, consider this scheme:

```
     12 bits           4 bits
 Sequence number   Fragment number
```

So if I send a sequence number with the value 258 (\x02\x01), it will actually be;

```
Fragment number :2
Sequence number :16
```

I'm wondering how i can have that 258 to be the actual sequence number, and not splitted this way.
Is there any simple way to achieve this with `struct` ?

UPDATE:

What i meant in my above question was:

I'm building a network packet generator that goes like this:

```
class PacketHeader(Packet):
fields = OrderedDict([
    ("head", "\x00"),
    ("headpad", "\x00"),
    ("headlen", "\x1a\x00" ),
    ("presentflag", "\x2e"),
    ("timestamp", "\x43\x10\x58\x16\xa1\x01\x00\x00"),
    ("flag", "\x03"),
    ("Sequencenum", "\x04\x00"), 
###12 bits of this 'short' is Seq num, 4 bits left are if this is a fragment or not(if it is, its value will be =>1, and will then represent the frag number.)

])
```

Later, I call my class and send the packet like this:

```
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=257))
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=258))
send(PacketHeader(Sequencenum=259))
```

I need to convert to a short the sequence number (in this case lets say 257), and take care of the 4 bits that represent the fragment number in that 16 bit short. I would prefer to always have fragment number set to 0, but have Sequencenum incremented correctly.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's not at all clear what you have, and what you want.   The title says "split a 16 bit value," but the text says, "not split."  Can you clarify?

Comment: I would like to know how do you split a short to have the expected values, in this case :
     Fragment number : 0
     Sequence number : 513

Hope this help :)

Comment: I think you're decoding the sequence number with the wrong endianness.

Comment: I should also note that the `struct` format should probably have an uppercase `H` rather than a lowercase one, unless you want possibly-negative sequence numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the line:

```
number_to_send = (sequence_number << 4) + fragment_number
bytes_to_send = struct.pack("!H", number_to_send)
```

And back:

```
sequence_number = struct.unpack("!H", bytes_to_send)[0] >> 4
```